# Android: Recent Suggestion listener to open custom activity

Tags: android, android-search

I have a searchView with RecentSuggestions and I want when someone press on one of the suggestions to open a different activity from the default that I state on AndroidManifest. I can't find anything to implement this. I tried to override the onQueryTextSubmit() but it didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **SearchView.OnSuggestionListener** interface and override its **onSuggestionClick(int position)** method. You can also have a look at android documentation: [Adding Recent Query Suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html)

Comment: It works :D but how to take the text of the suggestion? Because it returns the position of the list. I tried searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getItem(position); but it returns and object.

Comment: Great stuff! Do you populate the list with an adapter? the position will be the index of the text in the list, so you need to query the list index at the position value, if that makes sense. Try searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter() and see if that gets you on track

Comment: If getSuggestionsAdapter returns you a CursorAdapter you can try theCursorAdapter.getItem(position).toString() or perhaps Cursor c = theCursorAdapter.getCursor() and then c.getString(position)

Comment: I managed to do that with searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(2) for recent suggestions. Thank you very much for helping me :D :D